# How to access a website filemanager using HTML and PHP

Tags: html

Using HTML element

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="file" name="file"/>
</body>
</html>
```

we can browse our local systems files. But how to browse my website filemanager files using HTML element.I searched a lot online but dint find anything.

Comment: Thats actually a good question, want to know this myself! Welcome to stack overflow Vidhya.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to implement it. Or find an already implemented solution. It will involve both client and server sides.

Comment: If it involves both client and server sides,then is there no HTML elements for this??

Comment: No need to create what's been done already http://www.osfilemanager.com

Comment: can you give brief outline for how to use osfilemanager. I have installed it but couldn't to implement